# TeamCity - build fails for referenced projects at solution level

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a solution with 5 projects and 1 added "as reference" ,let name it "Common Project" (I added an existing project inside a solution folder). Because "Common project" was added as a reference. in the Solution file it displays the path as - "..\SharedProject\CommonProject.proj" where as other projects are having the full path. Because of this TeamCity build is failing as it was trying to reference the proj file based on the path from Solution file.

So I added an artifact for the CommonProject and I have added an artifact dependency in the main solution. But still build compile fails because it couldnt find the CommonProject dll in other projects.

Could someone please advise if I missed any step or suggest any other approach.

Thanks in advance

Sai

Comment: Ended up following the solution given in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17319720/924991

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extra build step in CommonProject in teamcity that copies the `dll` artifacts to a folder your main solution can find.